# Persistent disk losing some data

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a question regarding GCP Persistent Disk (SSD). I created a disk, I created a VM to which I added the disk. Then I ssh'd into the VM, I saw the disk, I formatted it and mounted it to my VM. Everything worked just fine, I was able to create some files there and use it as a normal disk. However, when I deleted the VM and created another VM some time later, mounted the same disk, the data seemed to be lost, I didn't see it.
This contradicts the name "persistent" which means I might be doing something wrong or misunderstanding something. I would be greateful for any help.

Comment: More details are required including original VM configuration, new VM confirmation, persistent disk partitioning, and formatting, etc. Persistent disks are persistent, but your configuration can overwrite/delete data.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you had posted your VM configuration, but if I had to guess you had the disk deletion rule in your VM set to delete the disk when you deleted your VM.

Edit your VM and make sure the "Deletion rule" setting is set to "Keep disk."

[image: VM disk deletion rule]